# Using both a having and nested (max) group function

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, max, having

I am trying to find the Staff member who has dealt with the maximum amount of orders, my
 following code is incorrect, if this could be corrected it would be great!

```
SELECT 
    c.Staff_No, s.First_name, s.Last_Name, COUNT(*) AS "Number Of Orders"          
FROM 
    Cust_Order c              
INNER JOIN 
    Staff s on c.Staff_No = s.Staff_No    
GROUP BY 
    c.Staff_No, s.First_name, s.Last_Name  
HAVING 
    Number Of Orders(max)  
ORDER BY 
    c.Staff_No;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to get this. One obvious way:

```
select
    Staff_No, First_name,Last_Name, ordcnt as "Number of Orders"
FROM
    (SELECT 
        c.Staff_No, s.First_name, s.Last_Name, COUNT(*) as ordcnt          
    FROM 
        Cust_Order c              
    INNER JOIN 
        Staff s on c.Staff_No = s.Staff_No    
    GROUP BY 
        c.Staff_No, s.First_name, s.Last_Name  
    ORDER BY 
        ordcnt desc)
where rownum<=1;
```